# Padding metal hooks on car trunk bike rack

Tags: car, moving

I bought [this trunk bicycle rack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TRTSAZM) on Amazon and I'm trying to effectively solve one issue I'm having with it before I use it...

The hooks that fasten it to your trunk are metal. There is no padding whatsoever. If I was driving a junker I wouldn't be so concerned, but that isn't the case as my car is barely a year old.

For reasons that should be obvious at this point, I'd rather not fasten even the empty rack to my trunk by the bare metal hooks as I *really* don't want to scratch or damage anything.

The pictures in the Amazon link above don't really show the hooks that well, but they are L/J-ish in shape, and maybe 3/4"-1" wide.

Does anyone have any (preferably) permanent solutions for how I could pad these hooks and prevent damage to my car? By "permanent" I mean something that won't/shouldn't deteriorate from reasonably long drives, while not impacting the integrity or intentions of the rack itself.

Comment: [These ones?](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51mQY3lx5dL.jpg)

Comment: @JustDoIt - Correct. Those are the hooks. Or at the very least, extremely similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an old bike tube laying around (or even a new one, if you're willing to spend a few bucks), you can cut it up and stick it between the hook and the trunk/hatch. If you don't plan on taking the rack off all the time you can just place them in there and they should stay. If you plan to remove the rack on a regular basis, you might consider two-sided taping them in, and/or keeping a little baggie full of spares in case you lose one.

Comment: After trying some of the other suggestions, many ended up too thick to "safely" close my trunk. I am not using the tube, but something similar (thin rubber tubing stuck to the hooks with gorilla tape) and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thats odd, considering grip pads arent that thick but as long as you got it working now is good @DangerZone

Comment: @JustDoIt - Yeah, I can definitely see them working on *some* car. The gap between by trunk and rest of the car is just a tad too narrow. I could maaaaybe close it if I slammed it down, but I'd rather not take that risk in damaging something.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do a custom size padding made out of lifting grip pads (pads weight lifters use to have a better grip of weights/bars) they're fairly cheap, durable and easy to custom size it to your needs. These will keep your car's integrity at ease while providing some extra grip for your bike rack.

[image]

Comment: The grip aspect is pretty nice! I went ahead and ordered some along with a bottle of super glue for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

May be shrink wrap may help you. Adjust the size (initial and final diameter), reel the rubber or foam-rubber into inside (or just skip this step), then combine and heat it via lighter, then cut the result to needed size.

Comment: I assume you mean heatshrink tubing as used for cables.  On that assumption, +1.

Comment: Chris H, yes, exactly heatshrink. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I *think* "shrink wrap" is more commonly used for this material in American English than it is in British English (the sort I know).  "Shrink wrap" is certainly used and understood in the context of cables.  Ther's nothing wrong with your English!

Answer (score 1):

Simple/cheap would be pipe lagging, available from any DIY store

[image]

It's slit right down one side [not easy to spot in the photo] & easy to lap over any flat edge. Comes in as many sizes & thicknesses as there are types of water pipe.
Costs mere pence per foot.
Also available in coated versions which are more resistant to wear.